# How can I pass change arguments into character in a function?

Tags: r, function, group-by, arguments, character

Give a minimum example.

`df <- data.frame("Treatment" = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2)), "Price" = 1:4, "Cost" = 2:5)`

I want to summarize the data by treatments for all the variables I have, and put them together, so I define a function to do this for each variable first, and then `rbind` them later on.

```
SummarizeFn <- function(x,y,z) {
                       x %>% group_by(Treatment) %>% 
                       summarize(n = n(), Mean = mean(y), SD = sd(y)) %>% 
                       cbind("Var" = rep(y, 3)) # add a column to show which variable those statistics belong to. 
                   }
SumPrice <- SummarizeFn(df, df$Price, "Price")
```

However, R tells me that object "Price" is not found. How to solve this problem?

Also, how to make y as a character indicating the mean and sd are of price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price isnt a variable, you need `SummarizeFn(df,df$Price)` because Price is just defined in your list df

```
SummarizeFn <- function(x,y,z)
{
df1<-(x %>% group_by(Treatment)
        %>% summarize(n = n(), Mean = mean(y), SD = sd(y))
      )

df1<- df1 %>% mutate ("Var" = z)

return(df1)
}

SumPrice <- SummarizeFn(df, df$Price,"Price")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and it works. But when I changed ```mean(y)``` to ```mean(x$y)```, it didn't work. What is the problem here? What about the second problem? Thanks again.

Comment: You insert the values x and y into the function. In your case x is the list "df" which contains Treatment, Price and Cost, but there is no single variable "Price" so nothing exists which you can put into y. R doesnt detect your "Price" as a character which you need here. Somehow it is possible to do it in this way but im not sure actually. Thinking about the second

Comment: Actually no need for a mutate function. ```df$Var = z``` can do the job. The main problem is that the ```group_by() %>% summarize``` does not work properly in a function environment.